# Pre-Allocation of std::map<unsigned long long,void *> , How to pre-allocate properly?

Tags: stl, dictionary

Problem:

I'm working with very large data-sets, up to a maximum of 8 * 1024 * 1024 identities;

1. I've pre-allocated an array of structures, pointed to by the void * portion.
2. The 'free' pointers are pushed on a stack, popped as they are used, and pushed as they are removed from the hash_map.  (this is close to 256mb of memory)
3. I've identified the majority of the system time / performance as being consumed in the add operations of the std::hash_map.

struct Order;
std::hash_map   OrderDatabase;

What I would really like to do, is just pass the MAX_ORDERS into the constructor:

std::hash_map   OrderDatabase(MAX_ORDERS);

// and have it pre-allocate the containers so that insertion / removal don't involved malloc/free.

Suggestions are appreciated!  I'm trying to stick to strictly STL/C++ as a side note.

Edit/Update:

I've also tried the following:

hash_map MapTest;
hash_map::allocator_type MapAlloc = MapTest.get_allocator();

pair *ary = MapAlloc.allocate(MAX_ORDERS); // the  problem here is that ulonglong is const!

The idea was to push each one unto a stack, and pop for alloc, and use insert instead of maptest[id] = ptr;

//Update 2:

1. Create stack< pair * >  pointer_stack, and push pre-allocated pointers,
2. Pop a pointer. Assign values;
3. Insert into hash_map:
4. Find the item, get a pointer to the address:  it appears the hash_map allocated a new pair even though I called insert.

This makes removal & pushing unto the stack not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `map`? Even if you defeat `malloc` slowliness with custom allocator, the `map`'s implementation will still have to perform tree rebalancing a lot of times, and I don't think you can change that.

If the map is intented to be read-only (i.e. the only use of `insert` is to populate it before using), simply have a sorted array of key/index pairs, and use binary search. Searches will then be as fast as `map`, and much less memory will be consumed. You can always wrap it with `operator[]` and iteration for convenience.

C++11 `unordered_map` allows preallocation via `reserve()` method. Search/insertion/removal will take constant time. However, it will consume more memory than std::map.

Comment: I will re-edit this, it should be hash_map in hind-sight.  Also, memory on the system will be in the 24-48gb range, any Memory->Time trade off is desired.  Pre-Reserving the memory is optimal even if its never used.

Comment: `hash_map` is analogous to `unordered_map` from C++11/Boost,  only that I don't see SGI/VC++ implementations having `reserve()` methods, so try using the one from Boost or C++11 instead, may be it will work better.

Comment: What about sorted array suggestion — does anything prevent you from using it?

Comment: It appears the problem is in the allocation / deallocation. After running profiling, it takes 20 seconds for insertion/removal.  I've avoided any external libraries up to this point (Boost/C++11/SGI/VC++) After using the TBB from Intel, this time dropped to 15ms.  I will continue to update until a complete solution is found